# load and click event on checkbox

Tags: jquery

I want to change the content of div on page load and on click according to checkbox state. i know i can place the if condition to ready function but I want to use the code once. is there
any way to do this as below code is working fine for click event but not on the document
load.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="a">
<div>change content</div>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('#a').on('load click', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
       $('div').html('new content');
  })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the change event and trigger it as well

```
$(function(){
  $('#a').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
       $('div').html('new content');
  }).trigger('change');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this (untested):

```
$(function() {
    $("#a").on('click', function() {
        //code
    });
    $("#a").trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: this will, however, trigger the click (*and actually change the state of the checkbox*)

Comment: Gaby aka G. Petrioli is right. i only want to check the state don't want to change it.